# 68000 Assembly Language - How to know wether an address is an absoulute long or short operand

Tags: 68000

For example: `MOVE.W $1234,$8000`

Could someone tell me what the source is using ( Long or short ) and what the destination is using (Long or short). Can you explain how to found this out.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean. `MOVE.W` is a `move word` instruction, which was supposed to be a 16-bit word. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I was referring to absolute long or absolute short addressing.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably whatever the assembler decides to use.

To force it, use an [appropriate suffix](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/68000_Assembly#Absolute_near_addressing):

```
move.w ($1234).w, ($8000).l
```

to use short (also called "near") source but long (aka "far") destination address.

In my (semi-ancient) experience, you don't need to care about this very often, just let the assembler do its job.

Answer (score 0):

Unless explicitly specified by hinting the assembler (the notation may slightly differ depending on the assembler used, $1234.w would hint the assembler to use short mode), it depends on the assembler you're using what is done by default.

A common and sensible choice is to use the shorter variant where possible; e.g. anyhing between -32768 to 32767 inclusive is assembled as short, anything else as long. Applying this rule, $1234 would be assembled as short, while $8000 would assemble as long (because $8000.w would yield an effective address of $FFFF8000 when evaluated by the processor; as explicitly stated in the 68k family manual, address operands less than 32 bits in size, are sign extended to 32 bits before being used).